# C# - Defining an event from a NET .dll file I added as a reference to my project

Tags: c#, .net, events, dll

I'm trying to define an event from a NET `.dll file` I added as a reference to my project.
All functions in the `.dll file(PICkitS.dll)` work fine, and all prototype headers are defined [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PICkitS_Function_Prototypes_v2-1.pdf)

I just don't know how to define/access  event functions.

The "event" function I need to access is this one(as defined in the `.pdf` above):

```
public delegate void OnReceive(byte masterid, byte[] data, byte length, byte error,
ushort baud, double time);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Triggered: When a frame is received, the DLL is in LISTEN mode and
// the frame is different than what is in the buffer.
// OR
// When a frame is received and the DLL is in DISPLAY_All mode
// AND
// In Master mode and sent a whole frame.
//
// Paramters: byte masterid - Frame ID
// byte[] data - array of data associated with ID
// - only contains data, not the ID
// byte length - bytecount of data only, not the ID
// ushort baud - value of baud rate received
// with frame data
// double time - time in seconds since last frame break
// byte error - Error code: 0 - no error
// 1 - timeout
// 2 - no sync break
// 3 - error resetting timestamp
// 4 - PKSA status error
// 5 - PKSA error event marker
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Question is :

How can I can fetch the data that is received when this "OnReceive" is triggered?

How can I add a function that triggers on this?

This question relates to defining the serialport "DataReceived" event - but since serialport is built into C# toolbox, to add it I just need to double click on the event properties and the function is automatically added...

*Also, would appreciate some references to learn about this event handling/adding better.*

Update:
Added the "OnReceive..." in Form initialization

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   PICkitS.LIN.OnReceive += new PICkitS.LIN.GUINotifierOR(LIN_Receive_Data);
}
```

And tried to define "LIN_Receive_Data"

```
private void LIN_Receive_Data(byte masterid, byte[] data, byte length, byte error, ushort baud, double time)
{
    // Add event handler code here.
}
```

Guess I'm doing something wrong, as the "LIN_Receive_Data" does not trigger when data is received.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Microchip documentation is targeted for VB. In C#, you have to register for the OnReceived event explicitey: `lin.OnReceive += MyOnReceiveMethod` where `lin` is the `PICkitS.LIN` object and `void MyOnReceiveMethod(byte masterid, byte[] data, byte length, byte error, ushort baud, double time)` is your method.

Comment: Thank you - still trying to implement it, not successful yet :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out finally, posting in case somebody runs into the same issue.
Added this in public Form1():

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PICkitS.LIN.OnAnswer += new PICkitS.LIN.GUINotifierOA(LinDongle_OnAnswer);
        PICkitS.LIN.OnReceive += new PICkitS.LIN.GUINotifierOR(LinDongle_OnReceive);
    }
```

Then defined the functions:

```
    public void LinDongle_OnAnswer(byte masterID, byte[] Data, byte length, byte error, ushort baudrate, double time)
    {
        //fetch the data
        for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            lin_data_received[i] = Data[i];
        }
    }

    public void LinDongle_OnReceive(byte masterID, byte[] Data, byte length, byte error, ushort baudrate, double time)
    {
        //Code
    }
```

LinDongle_OnAnswer triggers when LIN data is received.

Also, make sure PICkitS.dll is the latest version.
Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Events are little more the add and remove accessors around delegates - like properties are get and set.

The common pattern for events is to take 2 Arguments:

- object sender. I am pretty sure it is from the pre-generics days, but even now there are advantages to not limit the sender type
- EventsArgs. Or a derived class. If you got a bunch of arguments, put them into your custom EventArges implementation.

For examples, I can give you the code for [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged):

```
    //The delegate is defined in another part of the code
    //As is the custom EventArgs class
    public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);


    //external code can only add/remove from this
    //class code can read and fully empty it
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.  
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName  
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.  
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

CallerMember name is pretty much uniquely usefull for this specific Event. There is even a decent chance it was added *just for it*. The idea of a specific "raiseEvent" function is pretty common. Sometimes those are marked as proteted virtual instead of private, as overriding them might be sensical for inheritors.